# In MySQL User table and Login history log table with Left join gives an error for contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am trying to get all user information data that is on the **USER** table and also only the user's last login information(which is on another table called **LOGIN_HISTORY**).

I tried with Left join but MySQL is giving me the error which shows "`Expression #15 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'login_history.user_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`"

Here is the **USER** table

[image: USER table]

Please help!
and this is my **LOGIN_HISTORY** table.

[image: LOGIN_HISTORY table]

The output which I want is

[image]

I have tried this query, I don't know what I am missing but it is not giving me the desired output. I only want all the user information with his LAST login_datetime column. I tried the below query but it is showing all the user records with duplicate and all the login_datetime.

I tried:

```
select u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email, u.username, u.password, lh.login_datetime 
from user u 
left join login_history lh on u.id = lh.user_id 
group by u.id  
order by DATE(lh.login_history) desc;`
```

Please help!

Comment: `group by u.id` After this operation server must return only one row for each separate `u.id` value. In source tables a lot of different `lh.login_datetime` matches each `u.id`. What one value from all existing must be returned? Last? Tell this to server.

Comment: I edited my answer with a solution for users who have never logged in!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative method to that suggested above would be to do the following (fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fdf6b3c5fcce2137c98f814f24f2015d)):

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
  id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  email VARCHAR (256) NOT NULL
);
```

The number of fields is irrelevant, since you won't be grouping by them. This is just a sample for demonstration purposes.

Then:

```
CREATE TABLE login_history
(
  lh_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  login_dt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  
  CONSTRAINT lh_user_dt_uq UNIQUE (user_id, login_dt),  -- same user can't login at the same time
  
  CONSTRAINT lh_uid_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id)
  
);
```

Populate:

```
INSERT INTO user (email)
VALUES
('111@xyz.com'),
('222@xyz.com'),
('333@xyz.com'),
('444@xyz.com'),
('555@xyz.com'),
('666@xyz.com');
```

and:

```
INSERT INTO login_history (user_id, login_dt)
VALUES
(1, '2011-01-11'), (1, '2011-02-11'), (1, '2011-03-11'),
(2, '2012-01-12'), (2, '2012-02-12'), (2, '2012-03-12'),
(3, '2013-01-13'), (3, '2013-02-13'), (3, '2013-03-13'),
(4, '2014-01-14'), (4, '2014-02-14'), (4, '2014-03-14'), 
(5, '2015-01-15'), (5, '2015-02-15'), (5, '2015-03-15');
```

And the query would be:

```
SELECT u.*, tab.lh_id, tab.ldt
FROM user u
JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lh.user_id ORDER BY lh.login_dt DESC) AS rn,
    lh_id,
    lh.user_id AS id,
    lh.login_dt AS ldt
  FROM login_history lh
) tab
ON u.id = tab.id
WHERE tab.rn = 1
ORDER BY u.id;
```

Result:

```
id  email        lh_id  ldt
1   111@xyz.com     3   2011-03-11 00:00:00
2   222@xyz.com     6   2012-03-12 00:00:00
3   333@xyz.com     9   2013-03-13 00:00:00
4   444@xyz.com    12   2014-03-14 00:00:00
5   555@xyz.com    15   2015-03-15 00:00:00
```

which, by inspection, is correct!

Now, in the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fdf6b3c5fcce2137c98f814f24f2015d), I've done a performance analysis of the query proposed above and @Akina's answer - and you'll see that my query is less performant. "So, what's the point?" you might ask?

Well, imagine a scenario where you want the last **2** logins or **3** or the last **x** of them... - just change the desired values of rn (put `tab.rn <= 2` or `tab.rn IN (1,2)`- shown at bottom of fiddle)!

Using MySQL's [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html), in this case the [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) function (examples [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/)), you can answer many more questions of your data.

I would **strongly** urge you to become familiar with window functions like those used in the second piece of SQL - they are very powerful and well worth the effort to learn - they will repay that effort 10 times over...

### EDIT:

Following a query by the OP concerning users who have never logged in, I did the following ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fdf6b3c5fcce2137c98f814f24f2015d) - same as above).

In order to `JOIN` the `user` table to the `login_history` table with a field that doesn't exist in the `login_history`, we have to do a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` (the left join is automatically an outer one, so the `OUTER` keyword is optional).

I added a user `(6, 666@xyz.com)` (see above) who has no records in the login table.

Then, I used the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
  u.id,
  u.email,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lh.user_id ORDER BY lh.login_dt DESC) AS rn,
  lh.lh_id,
  lh.user_id AS luid,
  lh.login_dt AS ldt
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN login_history lh
ON u.id = lh.user_id
ORDER BY u.id DESC;
```

Result (snipped for brevity):

```
id  email         rn    lh_id   luid    ldt
6   666@xyz.com     1    NULL    NULL   NULL    
5   555@xyz.com     1      15       5   2015-03-15 00:00:00
5   555@xyz.com     2      14       5   2015-02-15 00:00:00
...
...
```

So, we see that through the `LEFT JOIN` we now have the user 6, but the corresponding records from the login history are `NULL` (as expected)!

Now we simply wrap the above query in another to get the latest (or 2 latest or 3...) login time(s) for a given user as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT 
    u.id,
    u.email,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lh.user_id ORDER BY lh.login_dt DESC) AS rn,
    lh.lh_id,
    lh.user_id AS luid,
    lh.login_dt AS ldt
  FROM user u
  LEFT JOIN login_history lh
  ON u.id = lh.user_id
) AS tab
WHERE tab.rn = 1  -- or tab.rn IN (1,2) - shown at the bottom of the fiddle
ORDER BY tab.id;
```

Result:

```
id  email          rn  lh_id    luid    ldt
1   111@xyz.com     1      3       1    2011-03-11 00:00:00
2   222@xyz.com     1      6       2    2012-03-12 00:00:00
3   333@xyz.com     1      9       3    2013-03-13 00:00:00
4   444@xyz.com     1     12       4    2014-03-14 00:00:00
5   555@xyz.com     1     15       5    2015-03-15 00:00:00
6   666@xyz.com     1   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I also added the results for [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) (available from MySQL >= [8.0.18](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-explain-analyze/)), and I also profiled the query ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fdf6b3c5fcce2137c98f814f24f2015d)).

As with the previous solution using the ROW_NUMBER() window function, it's a bit slower and the plan is more complex but, as I said, it is also potentially **far** more powerful down the line. I would urge you to test with your own system (H/ware & S/ware) and data to see which solution best suits your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the solution but only one thing, If any of the users doesn't have a login record and the above query is not showing that user information. Is there any way I can display that user information with null as login_dt as well?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will try to do by left join.

Comment: Thank you. It works great and I will explore more about your given suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email, u.username, u.password, 
       MAX(lh.login_datetime) login_datetime
from user u 
left join login_history lh on u.id = lh.user_id 
group by u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email, u.username, u.password
order by login_history desc;
```

Comment: It is giving me the max login_datetime. But, I also want to add the login_history id column, and then it is giving me the error again. Same as I have. How can I do that?

Comment: @Yash *I also want to add the login_history id column* Unclear. Edit your question and add desired output for shown soiurce data.